# parsing json response to scala seq of case class

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework, jackson

The below JSON is able to parse it but it is converting into a HashMap instead of a case class.

Input json:

```
 {
        "value": [
            {
                "field-1": 1,
                "field-2": 1,
                "field-3": 1,
                "field-4": ,
                "field-5": "filter",
                "field-6": 1,
                "field-7": 1.000,
                "field-8": 1.000,
                "field-9": 1,
                "field-10": 100,
                "field-11": "",
                "field-12": "",
                "field-13": "desc1",
                "field-14": "desc",
                "field-15": "con_type",
                "field-16": "local",
                "field-17": 9999,
                "field-18": "nosql",
                "field-19": "db1",
                "field-20": "sc1",
                "field-21": "tb1",
                "field-22": "uuid",
                "field-23": "getData",
                "field-24": "get",
                "field-25": "encode",
                "field-26": "categ",
                "field-27": 12,
                "field-28": 12,
                "field-29": 12,
                "field-30": 12,
                "field-31": "2022-02-15 01:07:22.000 +0530",
                "field-32": "2022-02-15 01:07:29.000 +0530",
                "field-33": "2022-02-15 01:07:31.000 +0530",
                "field-34": false
            },
     {
                "field-1": 1,
                "field-2": 1,
                "field-3": 1,
                "field-4": ,
                "field-5": "filter",
                "field-6": 1,
                "field-7": 1.00,
                "field-8": 1.00,
                "field-9": 1,
                "field-10": 100,
                "field-11": "",
                "field-12": "",
                "field-13": "desc1",
                "field-14": "desc",
                "field-15": "con_type",
                "field-16": "local",
                "field-17": 9999,
                "field-18": "nosql",
                "field-19": "db1",
                "field-20": "sc1",
                "field-21": "tb1",
                "field-22": "job",
                "field-23": "getData",
                "field-24": "get",
                "field-25": "encode",
                "field-26": "categ",
                "field-27": 12,
                "field-28": 12,
                "field-29": 12,
                "field-30": 12,
                "field-31": "2022-02-15 01:07:22.000 +0530",
                "field-32": "2022-02-15 01:07:29.000 +0530",
                "field-33": "2022-02-15 01:07:31.000 +0530",
                "field-34": false
            }
       ]
    }

    def Get[T](uri: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): HttpResponse[T] = {
        val request   = BasicGetRequest(uri)
        val parsed_body: T = toACaseClass[T](request.body) //implementation is below
        HttpResponse(make_request.headers, parsed_body, make_request.status) // implementation is below
      }
    
    
    def toACaseClass[T](value: String)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): T = {
        val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
        mapper.readValue(value, ct.runtimeClass).asInstanceOf[T]
      }
    
      case class HttpResponse[T](headers: Map[String, String], body: T, status: Int)
```

### Issue:

while parsing the Json response (request.body) to a seq of case class, I am getting the response in a Hashmap Instead of getting it in a case class. Please see the below screenshot for more info

How can we convert the response which is in the Hashmap to case class??

Comment: Have you considered using another JSON library like **circe**?

Comment: please try using spray_json

Comment: should not use any external libraries. Is it possible to solve this using Jackson or play- JSON